# NodeJS & Express: Can't get access to a function outside a folderr

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, node-modules

I Can't get access to the function i export in app.js

in app.js file:

```
function getConnection() {
    return mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'Academind'
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getConnection: function () {
        return getConnection()
    }
}
```

in my orders.js file:

```
const app = require('../../app')

function getConnection() {
    return app.getConnection() // doesn't work 
}
```

I get this error:

> app.getConnection is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with how you're exporting your `getConnection(...`) method, you should change it to the following to resolve your issue:

**app.js**

```
function getConnection() {
    return mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'Academind'
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getConnection: getConnection
}
```

then use it in the modules that require it as follows:

**orders.js**

```
const app = require('../../app')
const getConnection = app.getConnection

// get your database connection string 
getConnection()
```

Previously you were creating an anonymous function which called your `getConnection()` function which returned your database connection string value instead of that function. This is why you're seeing the following error:

> app.getConnection is not a function

because it's a string with your database connection details and not a function.

Now, we are exporting your `getConnection()` function as a function, called appropriately `getConnection()`, to be used in other modules.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: But why does it return a string value when I return a function ?

Comment: hey did you reread my answer? It's because the function you were exporting was actually calling your function called getConnection() and this value is a connection string given by mysql connector. Does that make sense? Basically you were actually calling the function instead of exporting it. So it returned a value, of your connection string, instead of the function itself

Comment: Ok thanks. On app.js this doesn't work which is very weird but on another file it works

Comment: You are exporting this function within app.js so it doesn't make sense to use import and use it there. If you want to use it within app.js I would move that code into a new module, maybe call it Config.js, and then require that new module within app.js